# prove kn objects of n colors can be placed in n boxes with maximum of 2 colors per box

Tags: trigonometry

the complete question is this:
prove that kn cubes with n colors can be placed in n boxes, where each box can have a maximum of 2 different colors.
(count of cubes of each color is not necessarily k, there can be more cubes from a certain color) and each box should contain exactly k cubes.

I know that I should use an inductive proof and the base cases for n=1 and n=2 are obvious, but since there are a different number of cubes of each color, the main part of the proof is challenging for me.
thanks!

Comment: This is not clear. Why can't we just assign one of the $n$ colours to each of the $n$ boxes and put all cubes of that colour into that box to satisfy the requirement?

Comment: sorry, I forgot a part. each box should contain exactly k cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one colour $c$ of which there are at most $k$ cubes and at least one other colour $d$ of which there are at least $k$ cubes. Put all cubes of colour $c$ into one box and fill the rest with cubes of colour $d$. Now you have $n-1$ boxes for $k(n-1)$ cubes with at most $n-1$ colours.